# Inserting XML Data in multiple occurence

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, sqlxml

I have a XML Column in My Table. The XML Structure is something like this:

```
   <Nodes>
    <Node>
     <Name>a</Name>
    </Node>
    <Node>
     <Name>a</Name>
    </Node>
   </Nodes>
```

I am trying to insert  in both the nodes:
I tried this:

```
  SET @xml.modify('       
    insert <Phone>111</Phone> 
   into (/Nodes/Node)[1]')
```

But this inserts Phone in just first occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, you cannot update multiple nodes inside xml, you can use loop:

```
select @i = @xml.value('count(Nodes/Node)', 'int')

while @i > 0
begin
   set @xml.modify('insert <Phone>111</Phone> into (/Nodes/Node)[sql:variable("@i")][1]') 

   set @i = @i - 1
end

select @xml
```

or you can reconstruct your xml like this:

```
select
    111 as Phone,
    t.c.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Name
from @xml.nodes('Nodes/Node') as t(c)
for xml path('Node'), root('Nodes')
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21804)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks. The 1st one works good.